# WIndows Mobile 6 SDK - string.Split and StringSplitOptions - can't find

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I try to do the

```
using System;

"some/String".Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

but the compiler can't find the `StringSplitOptions` enum. How to fix it ?

Comment: You can not fix this, the CF runtime libs are not the same as the full framework ones and to decrease mem use etc, they do not mirror the full framework. So you will find 'missing' full framework features all the time. You may implement your own String.Split to add what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile uses .NET *Compact* Framework, which does not support StringSplitOptions.

The only String.Split overload implemented in the Compact Framework [is Split(Char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).